# Option for Second Alert on Calendar Events Disappeared After Mojave 10.14.6 Update

Tags: calendar, ical

I just updated my Macbook Pro to Mojave 10.14.6 and noticed that I can no longer set a second alert on events I add to my Calendar. I'm not using any external calendars or accounts, just my iCloud. I can still set second alerts on my iPhone, just not my computer.

Comment: If you double-click the calendar event, then click on the alert area, does it have a + sign next to the alert?

Comment: No, the plus sign is no longer appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what is your default calendar settings. If you select iCloud Calendar then you will have plus sign option next to the alert.

[image]